# How does one populat input text field using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery

I am really new to jquery.Well i have two input text fields and i have managed to attatch autosuggestion list on both the input fields via the following function

```
function lookup(inputString,tableName,colName,divId,listId) {
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            // Hide the suggestion box.
            $(divId).hide();
        } else {
            $.post("customers.php", {queryString: ""+inputString+"",table:""+tableName+"",col:""+colName+""}, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $(divId).show();
                    $(listId).html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    } // lookup
```

and my form looks like this

```
    <div>
            <form>
                <div>
                    Location
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString" onkeyup="lookup(this.value,'countries','value','#suggestions','#autoSuggestionsList');" onblur="fillValues(this.value,'#inputString','#suggestions');" autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="http://localhost/ci/css/images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
                    <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList"  >
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div>
                    Favourite Product
                    <br />
                    <input type="text" size="30" value="" id="inputString1" onkeyup="lookup(this.value,'product','value','#suggestions1','#autoSuggestionsList1');"
"fillValues(this.value,'#inputString1','#suggestions1');"  autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>

                <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions1" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="http://localhost/ci/css/images/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px;left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
                    <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList1" >
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and fillValues function looks like this

```
function fillValues(thisVal,inputId,divId)
    {   
       $(inputId).val(thisValue);
       setTimeout("$("+divId+").hide();",200)

    }
```

Now when the user clicks on a value on the list the input text field should be filled with that value.however i am not being able to do so.What am i missing?

p.s. the autosuggestion list is successfully shown and my customers.php is working fine.

Comment: to target an element with its id via jquery , it is like this $("#elementID")

Comment: also you say that when the user click on a value ..., where is this in your code ? the function you wrote will not be called until you catch the user click

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Hey thanks but i have passes my values of ids with # so end result is just as you have mentioned in the first comment.Also there's a function named onblur which helps .Anyways thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

i think your function must be like this , oyu have to add a '#' to target an element with its id

```
function fillValues(thisVal,inputId,divId)
    {   
       $("#"+inputId).val(thisValue);
       setTimeout("$(#"+divId+").hide();",200)

    }
```

to  target element with its id we use '#' 
 to  target element with its class we use '.'

Comment: Hey i have passed the values of ids with a # so i dont need to place the hash again:)